# How to connect a submit click event to an input value to query an api

Tags: javascript, api, onclick, dom-events

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    // Checking if the button was clicked
    if (!event.target.matches("#button")) return;


 
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'google-web-search.p.rapidapi.com',
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    };

    fetch('https://google-web-search.p.rapidapi.com/?query=Nike&gl=US&max=10' , options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => rendersearch(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
  });

  function rendersearch(response) {
    const setup = document.getElementById("setup");

    setup.innerHTML = response.setup;
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <input id="input" type="text" name="name" value=""> 
    <button id="button" type='button'>Submit</button>
</form>
<p id="setup"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to use user input to query an api and get the search result displayed on the screen.
i'm having trouble connecting the button click event with the input change listener. kindly help

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    // Checking if the button was clicked
    if (!event.target.matches("#button")) return;


 
  
    };

    fetch('https://google-web-search.p.rapidapi.com/?query=Nike&gl=US&max=10' , options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => rendersearch(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
  });

  function rendersearch(response) {
    const setup = document.getElementById("setup");

    setup.innerHTML = response.setup;
  
  }
```

i'm getting undefined when i try to search but in the console.log its fetching correctly i dont know what might be the problem

Comment: Can you pls add your htlm code?

Answer (score 0):

Very likely the `response` object does not contain a field called `setup`, maybe  you can try to change

> .then(response => rendersearch(response))

to

> .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))

to see what response you got in the console first, then pass the desired field to `rendersearch()`

Comment: @sam did you use ``JSON.stringify(response))`` like here?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had a similar issue to you and this is what I found to be the solution notice how I assigned a variable (button) to the thing I wanted the user to click on (a button)

and then rather than document.addEventListener
I used button.addEventListener (you can change button to the variable assigned to whatever thing you wanted to be clicked and it should then work your issue is simply incorrect syntax for the addEventlistner function no other line of your code seems to be incorrect

I hope that helped

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDUy3.png)

Comment: put code inside post, not in image, please

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing tag `};` to mucht, the event listener should work if you delete it. I do not know if the API call is working corectly.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    // Checking if the button was clicked
    if (!event.target.matches("#button")) return;

    //delete this one and it should work:
    //};

    fetch('https://google-web-search.p.rapidapi.com/?query=Nike&gl=US&max=10' , options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => rendersearch(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
  });
```

Comment: kindly look at it again i have updated the code, still not working thanks

Comment: response hase no property ".setup"

Comment: It's now returning [object Object]

Comment: Did you do this ```.then(response =>  rendersearch(JSON.stringify(response)))``` and delete the second ``.then()``

Comment: Yes but it fetched {}

Comment: Do you have a working key? I got an 403 (Forbidden) error (what is normal). What is the http response?

Comment: I would recomend you to ask the question again but different, for example: fetch response is '{}' or something since it is not about the button anymore.

Comment: It is also a posibility the respons is suposed to be empty.

Comment: its a google search api